# Jenkins Workflow Plugin How to Fail a Build

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm currently using the Jenkins Workflow plugin, I have a master groovy script that calls other child groovy scripts.

What would be best way to fail the build from the child script such? At the moment I'm throwing an exception from the child script but this create a lot of output in the console since it prints the whole stack trace.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Return a certain value from the child script or set a certain object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `error` step, which does not print a stack trace.

Comment: Cool, I've also found that it might be possible to use currentBuild.Result but the error step might be better.

Comment: Yes you can set `currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'` if you want to just set the build status without stopping the flow.

Comment: That was the piece I was missing. Thanks!